# How do I make a pygame sprite "shoot" another out

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make the ladybug sprite shoot out the egg sprite whenever a condition is true

In this case that condition would be when the ladybug sprite hits the leaf sprites

I've managed to make that sort of happen but I'm unable to have it repeat it self
It is only shooting once, I've tried a few different ways to make it work but I have been unsuccessful.

```
import pygame
import sys
import random

pygame.init()
res = (1000, 600)
pygame.display.set_caption("placeholder")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(res)
worldbg = pygame.image.load("worldbg.png").convert_alpha()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Egg(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = random.randint(1, 1000)
        self.y = random.randint(1, 600)
        self.x_speed = 0.2
        self.y_speed = 0.2
        self.x_direction = 1
        self.y_direction = 1

        self.frame = 0
        super().__init__()
        self.sprites = []
        self.is_animating = False

        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load("egg.png"))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load("egg.png"))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load("egg.png"))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load("egg.png"))



        self.current_sprite = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[self.current_sprite]

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [x, y]

    def animate(self):
        self.is_animating = True

    def kill(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill(self)

    def update(self):
        if self.is_animating:
            self.current_sprite += 0.20
            if self.current_sprite >= len(self.sprites):
                self.current_sprite = 0
                self.is_animating = False
        self.image = self.sprites[int(self.current_sprite)]

# this makes the bullet act like a heatsinking missile

        if self.x < player.rect.x + 40:
            self.x_direction = 8
            self.x_direction = 4
        elif self.x > player.rect.x + 40:
            self.x_direction = -8
            self.x_direction = -4

        if self.y > player.rect.y + 40:
            self.y_direction = -8
            self.y_direction = -4

        elif self.y < player.rect.y + 40:
            self.y_direction = 8
            self.y_direction = 4

        self.x_speed = random.randint(1, 2) * self.x_direction
        self.y_speed = random.randint(1, 2) * self.y_direction

        self.x += self.x_speed
        self.y += self.y_speed
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y



        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())

eggmis = False
lvl4 = True
lvl4sr = 0

ladybug = Ladybug(0, 0)
ladybug_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
ladybug_sprites.add(ladybug)
ladybug.rect.x = 0
ladybug.rect.y = 0
ladybug.list = pygame.sprite.Group()
ladybug.list.add(ladybug)

egg = Egg(0, 0)
egg_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
egg_sprites.add(egg)
egg.rect.x = 0
egg.rect.y = 0
egg.list = pygame.sprite.Group()
egg.list.add(egg)


 # while loop starts here but I'll skip that

 if lvl4sr >= 12:
        lvl4 = True

    if lvl4 is True:



        chl = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ladybug, leaf_sprites, False, pygame.sprite.collide_circle_ratio(0.2))
        if chl:
            playerhp -= 20
            eggmis = True
          
   if eggmis is True:

        ehp = pygame.sprite.collide_circle(egg, player)
        if ehp is True:
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill(egg)

        egg_sprites.draw(screen)
        egg_sprites.update()
        lvl4sr -= 6
```

this makes the bullet fires one time once the condition is reached then doesn't work

Comment: You have both `pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)` and `super().__init__()`.  Because of the inherited `Sprite` object these both do the same thing.  You only need the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one typical approach for implementing this "create & animate a transient object" type problem:

```
egg_list = []    # all eggs are held in this list/spritegroup/whatever

### main loop

# Update all entities:
for egg in egg_list:
    egg.update()                          # move every egg by their (dx, dy)

# Handle collisions
for egg in egg_list:                      # collide every egg
    if ( egg.collideswith( player ) ):
        # remove egg from egg_list        # the egg is 'used up'
        # do some stuff to player

# Paint the screen
background.draw( window )
player.draw( window )
for egg in egg_list:                      # paint every egg to the window
    egg.draw( window )
```

Note that we *never* handle a specific `egg` arbitrarily.  It's always handling whatever `egg` is found in `egg_list`.  It doesn't matter if `egg_list` is a Sprite Group, list, dictionary, whatever - the same program flow is used.  The take-away point is that don't care how many eggs are in the list, we process all of them, in turn, the same way.

The benefit of this approach, is that now *all* egg handling is done as a batch.  So now when an `egg` object is created, it will automatically be moved, painted, animated etc.

So when your `LadyBug` object collides with a `Leaf` object, we can just add a new `egg` to the `egg_list`.

```
if ( ladybug.collideswith( leaf ) ):
    egg_list.append( Egg( ladybug.x, ladybug.y, ... ) )   # create an egg
```

Your code is not handling the updating of `egg` objects as a batch, and it is not creating a new `egg` when the `ladybird` collides with the `leaf`.

Obviously the Sprite Group automates a lot of this for you, in particular the updating, colliding and drawing.  But you need the supporting code to properly use those functions.  Maybe you had all this, but didn't add it to the question.